# Listview order.runOnUiThread?

Tags: java, android, listview

Hi guys I have a problem with my `ListView`...
This is my code:

```
     private ArrayAdapter<String> adapter ;  

      private ProgressDialog m_ProgressDialog = null; 
        private ArrayList<Order> m_orders = null;
        public OrderAdapter m_adapter;
        private Runnable viewOrders;

        public class Order {

            private String orderName;
            private String orderStatus;

            public String getOrderName() {
                return orderName;
            }
            public void setOrderName(String orderName) {
                this.orderName = orderName;
            }
            public String getOrderStatus() {
                return orderStatus;
            }
            public void setOrderStatus(String orderStatus) {
                this.orderStatus = orderStatus;
            }
        }
        private class OrderAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Order> {

            private ArrayList<Order> items;

            public OrderAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId, ArrayList<Order> items) {
                    super(context, textViewResourceId, items);
                    this.items = items;
            }

            @Override
            public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

                    View v = convertView;
                    if (v == null) {
                        LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater)getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                        v = vi.inflate(R.layout.list_single, null);
                    }
                    Order o = items.get(position);
                    if (o != null) {
                          //  TextView tv2 = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tv2);
                        TextView tv1 = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tv1); //codice volo
                        TextView tv2 = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tv2); // citta

                        TextView tv5 = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tv5); //stato volo
                        TextView tv6 = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tv6); //ora prevista
                        TextView tv7 = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tv7); //ora stimata                           if (tt != null) {

                        tv1.setText("VOLO: "+o.getOrderName());                            
                        }
                    return v;
            }    
        }

        private void getOrders(){
              try{
                  m_orders = new ArrayList<Order>();
                  Order o1 = new Order();
                  o1.setOrderName("SF services");
                  o1.setOrderStatus("Pending");
                  Order o2 = new Order();
                  o2.setOrderName("SF Advertisement");
                  o2.setOrderStatus("Completed");
                  m_orders.add(o1);
                  m_orders.add(o2);
                     Thread.sleep(2000);
                  Log.i("ARRAY", ""+ m_orders.size());
                } catch (Exception e) { 
                  Log.e("BACKGROUND_PROC", e.getMessage());
                }
                runOnUiThread(returnRes);
            }
        public LayoutInflater getSystemService(String layoutInflaterService) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return null;
        }

        private Runnable returnRes = new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                if(m_orders != null && m_orders.size() > 0){
                    m_adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    for(int i=0;i<m_orders.size();i++)
                    m_adapter.add(m_orders.get(i));
                }
                m_ProgressDialog.dismiss();
                m_adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
          };

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

       View ios = inflater.inflate(R.layout.arrivi, container, false); 


       m_orders = new ArrayList<Order>();
       this.m_adapter = new OrderAdapter(getActivity(), R.layout.list_single, m_orders);
               setListAdapter(getActivity(),m_adapter);

       viewOrders = new Runnable(){
           @Override
           public void run() {
               getOrders();
           }
       };
   Thread thread =  new Thread(null, viewOrders, "MagentoBackground");
       thread.start();
       m_ProgressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(getActivity(),    
             "Please wait...", "Retrieving data ...", true);

//   new MyTask().execute("");
   return ios;

}      


private void setListAdapter(FragmentActivity activity,
        OrderAdapter m_adapter2) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
```

In eclipse I get this error:
The method runOnUiThread(Runnable) is undefined for the type arrivi
This code isn't in MainActivity but in a fragment named arrivi.
The file XML is list_single.xml and is associated at custom rows!
Can you help me please?

Another question...
How to implement `AsyncTask` for replacing `Thread`?

```
public class MyTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
    ProgressDialog prog;
    String info;
```

.... When I run my app... it's in loop in "Retrieving data ..."
Thank you so much!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create an instance for `AsyncTask` like this and execute your program on background.

```
 new AsyncTask<Void, Integer, Long>(){
        @Override
        protected Long doInBackground(Void... params) {
            try {

                // call you method here

            } catch (Exception ex) {
                // handle the exception here
            }
            return null;
        }
    }.execute();
```

`runOnUiThread` is used to execute some program in main `Thread`. When you call `runOnUiThread` , the action will be executed immediately if we are already in `UIThread` else will be posted in `Queue`.

You need to use the `Activity` `Context` associated with your `Fragment` to `runOnUiThread'.

```
 getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            // execute your code here
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

runOnUiThread is a method of [Activity](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html) subclasses. Inside a Fragment :

```
getActivity().runOnUiThread(runnable);
```